# Advanced Lemmas and Theorems in theory of ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

What are advanced lemmas and theorems, maybe also more recent ones, in the theory of ordinary differential equations that are not contained or not so much emphasized in textbooks on ODE theory?

To give an idea: I would consider the lemma of Gronwall basic.

Comment: In my view the basic block ends with the maximal solution and smoothness properties of the flow. Then you get a block on the Sturm-Liouville theory, a block on ODE on manifolds, geodesics, Lie-groups and symmetries, connected to that a block on Hamiltonian systems and classical mechanics. These are all still standard for text books. Somewhat across the previous blocks are special functions (Bessel etc.), periodic systems and Floquet theory, perturbations and bifurcations. Then there is the limit case for the method of lines for hyperbolic PDE, semi-groups of propagators,...

Comment: What about nonlinear ODEs and systems of nonlinear equations and the longterm behavior of ODEs?

Comment: General ODE including systems and non-linear are parts of the basic block. Contrarily, linear systems, esp. with constant coefficients and their geometric picture, could be considered a mini-block at the intersection of the basic and Lie-group block. // Yes, longterm-behavior, asymptotics and the geometry of the flow function can be considered as another block, which is also connected to the mini-block on linear systems.